# Margin vector in apply in R

Tags: r, function, apply

I am confused about the margin vector in apply. Lets say we have the standard data set Iris3 in R, which is 50x4x3. So 4 observations on 50 specimens each of 3 species. Why does apply with a margin of c(2,3) give me the mean of each variable by species. I just don't get the logic of specifying the margin varibale.

Answer (score 7):

The vector of margins specifies the dimension(s) that you want to hold fixed while you `apply` over the other free dimension(s). So specifying the margin of `c(2,3)` states that you want to apply the function over the first dimension (50 observations each) for every combination of the other two dimensions, measurement type and species.

```
> dim(iris3)
[1] 50  4  3
> apply(iris3,c(2,3),mean)
         Setosa Versicolor Virginica
Sepal L.  5.006      5.936     6.588
Sepal W.  3.428      2.770     2.974
Petal L.  1.462      4.260     5.552
Petal W.  0.246      1.326     2.026
```

Comment: Beat me to it - I was typing when your answer popped up.

Comment: I feel you - it happens to me a lot, as well.

Comment: Ok got it, so is it fair to say that the unspecified dimension gets "collapsed"?

Comment: @user1247384 That seems accurate.